# $\Delta v$ to raise the apogee of an orbit?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, rocket-science

I was just wondering why it takes more delta v to increase the apogee of an orbit from 1000 km to 11000 km than to increase the apogee of an orbit from 200000 km to 210000 km (from a fixed perigee at 200 km)?

Is this caused by the Oberth effect or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you get further away from a massive body, the force of gravity decreases, meaning it takes less energy to climb by a fixed distance. A 10000km increase in distance results in a bigger potential energy change when close to a massive body, and a smaller potential energy change when far from that body. You'll require a bigger energy input/delta-v to climb the same distance when lower in a gravity well.

Consider the case where you are nearly at escape velocity, with an apogee at some very large but finite distance away - as you approach escape velocity, the apogee height increases by an *arbitrary* amount for a finite delta-v. Since your original apogee was already located in a spot with hardly any gravitational force, it takes very little delta-v to overcome it. When very far from a massive body, you can climb higher practically "for free", which you cannot do when close to a massive body.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation !